# Which app should I select when inserting my phone into the car dock?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, tasker, car-dock, motorola-droid-bionic

I have a Tasker profile conditional on the phone being in the Car Dock.   When I insert the phone in the dock, I sometimes get a prompt to choose which application to launch -- either Tasker or "Smart Dock", a built-in app.  (When I don't get the prompt, neither seems to be notified).  There is also an option to make the setting stick.   I want Tasker to be notified, but the built-in app to launch.   Which should I choose?

edit: I get the same prompt when removing the phone from the dock.

Comment: I have not narrowed down the case(s) where the prompt doesn't occur, but I suspect it has to do with having an app in the foreground when the phone is inserted in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasker should be seeing the event even if the system doesn't have it set as the default handler, so you should be safe setting Smart Dock as the default. (That said, you could also have Tasker handle the launch of Smart Dock.)